# ShellShock vulnerability and Java Web Applications

Tags: java, unix, shellshock

I am running a java webapplication ( Spring 3.2 based) on linux hosts.
The linux hosts are vulnerable to the ShellShock vulnerability.

Can someone exploit this vulnerabiity on my website ?

Comment: Oracle has a list with its vulnerable apps http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/alert-cve-2014-7169-2303276.html

Comment: Thanks for link, but this is not what I was asking for.. i was more interested in knowing if a webapp be exploited.

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult to answer, as no one here does know how your application is built.

As long as you are not executing (*either directly or indirectly*) any system commands your application should be save.

There is only a risk when you execute commands (*either directly or indirectly*) in the shell out of your application.

This risk is very high if you execute shell commands (*either directly or indirectly*) that your users are entering as then your system is vulnerable.

Executing shell commands out of a Java web application is very unusual and not needed in almost all cases.

Comment: Uwe : I am not running any shell commands through my Java application. As I mentioned its Spring 3.2 based. It is a user management website. Ofcourse I get the user agent, IP and other browser data, and pass it to down stream applications.

Comment: @NoviceUser I've extended my answer. All risk also exists if you execute such commands indirectly. As I wrote an definitive answer is difficult as nobody here knows if any commands are executed (either directly or indirectly).